# MVC3 calling controller passing variables via JavaScript - that works with Android

Tags: javascript, android-browser

I have some standard code that looks like this

```
window.location.href = "/Home/Foo?Name=" + $('#Name').val() + "&Email=" + $('#Email').val();
```

This works as expected on a standard **computer browser** but it seems to fail when running on **Android**.
Anybody knows WHY this code does **NOT work** on Android ??

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: it works on iPhone, on any browser from a PC ..but nothing happens in Android. The Javascript function does get called as I'm doing some validations before ..but that line of code does NOT redirect the user to the next page.

U can see it at www.RightToDignity.org

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those values by calling `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: No. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Right ..but it works on other platforms so not sure that makes the cause for Android not to process the href value cause that page would handle no params if needed